# Detect if an HMENU is a popup or dropdown menu

Tags: winapi, menu

Ist it possible, given a HMENU, to detect if it's a popup or a drop down menu?

I want to create a (deep, modified) copy of an existing menu, and depending on this property I need to use either `CreatePopupMenu` or `CreateMenu`, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Raymond Chen [says here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/30/46594.aspx) (with my emphasis):

> `CreateMenu` creates a horizontal menu bar, suitable for attaching to a
>   top-level window. This is the sort of menu that says "File, Edit", and
>   so on.  `CreatePopupMenu` creates a vertical popup menu, suitable for
>   use as a submenu of another menu (either a horizontal menu bar or
>   another popup menu) or as the root of a context menu.
>
> If you get the two confused, you can get strange menu behavior.
>   Windows on rare occasions detects that you confused the two and
>   converts as appropriate, but I wouldn't count on Windows successfully
>   reading your mind.
>
> **There is no way to take a menu and ask it whether it is horizontal or
>   vertical. You just have to know.**

Answer (score 1):

Not clear with hmenu:

1) If you talk about hmenu, corresponding to the existing window (class #32768), it is sufficient to verify (via GetGUIThreadInfo) GUITHREADINFO.flags: availability GUI_INMENUMODE without GUI_POPUPMENUMODE without GUI_SYSTEMMENUMODE means that this menu - drop down.

2) If you talk about hmenu, existing in memory, we must find the root parent of this hmenu (btw, for menu there may be more than one, in contrast to the root parent window).
Then call TrackPopupMenu for found root parent and on WM_ENTERIDLE get hwnd appropriate window (class #32768) and call GetClientRect: if Rect =0, then the root parent = menubar (which can be created via LoadMenu(Indirect) or via CreateMenu), which means that the original hmenu - drop down (which can be created not only via CreatePopupMenu, but also via CreateMenu).

As for link to R.Chen. In reality the system always remembers exactly how was created hmenu in memory. But this mechanism (like so much else concerning the menu) is undocumented and Raymond obviously did not consider it necessary to uncover it...